# python django only the first statement statement can be accessed

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

i can acccess only the first statement in my name app

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function searched(){
    {% for names in name %}
        nameSearched = document.getElementById('name').value;
        document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = nameSearched;
            if (nameSearched == "{{ names.First }}" ){
                document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "{{ names.Last }}";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "none";
            }
    {% endfor %}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Check the `searched()` function in the browser. Does its content make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your function `searched()` in the script-tag.

If you have for example following `name`-instances:

```
[
    {
        'First': 'foo',
        'Last': 'bar',
    },
    {
        'First': 'foobar',
        'Last': 'barfoo',
    }
]
```

So your rendered `if`-`else` in the function would look like this:

```js
function searched(){
    nameSearched = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if ("foo" == nameSearched) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    if ("bar" == nameSearched) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```

So as you can see, you are *always* running into the `else` if you entered `foo`.

What you could do is the following in your `for`-loop:

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function searched(){
      nameSearched = document.getElementById('name').value;
      {% for names in name %}
        {% if forloop.first %}
          if ("{{ names.First }}" == nameSearched) {
            document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "{{ names.Last }}";
          }
        {% else %}
          else if ("{{ names.First }}" == nameSearched) {
            document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "{{ names.Last }}";
          }
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      {% if name %}
        else {
          document.getElementById('dis').innerHTML = "none";
        }
      {% endif %}
    }
</script>
```

This would result in the following:

```js
function searched(){
    nameSearched = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if ("foo" == nameSearched) {
        ...
    }
    else if ("foobar" == nameSearched) {
        ...
    }
    else {
        ...
    }
}
```